# Input type="time" перекрывает кастомное модальное окно

Tags: javascript, alert

Всем привет, решил написать свой собственный alert, но при его вызове обнаружил, что открытое поле input его перекрывает. Z-index у модального окна равен 999999.
[image: Скришот проблемы]

Comment: И почему это проблема? В каком разумном сценарии у вас эти два объекта могут быть  показаны одновременно?

Comment: А так вообще-то и старый добрый select перекроет ваш алерт. Просто потому что он (и time) рисуются не в документе

Comment: И каким тогда методом можно зыкрыть time picker, при открытии модального окна?

Comment: Что касается сценария, то alert вызывается каждый раз, при выборе времени, если последнее не соответствует условию, в данном случае, оно меньше текущего времени.

Comment: Ну так не надо вызывать алерт пока я ещё не определился со временем. В общем, кмк проблема не решаемая, но при этом на самом деле не очень актуальна при нормальном подходе к вёрстке

Comment: Проблему решил, путем навешивания функции вызова alert на атрибут onBlur, а не onChange тега input.